# How do I query SQL Server for a record with multiple key/value pair constraints?

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, t-sql

I'm using Entity Framework, and have an entity that has a collection of key/value pairs.  I want to be able to search for an entity based on those pairs.

Here are my tables:

StoredDocuments:

[image]

StoredDocumentKeywordValues:

[image]

So if I searched for entities with key k1 and value v1, I'd want StoredDocumentIds 1 and 2.

If I search for k1/v1, k2/v2, I'd want only StoredDocumentId 1

If I search for k1/v1, k4/v4, I'd get nothing

A linq statement would be ideal, but I couldn't figure it out.  Closest I got using SQL was ORing together all the individual key/value statements, but the case where a key/value didn't exist threw me.  What I really need is all the key/value pairs ANDed together:

If a StoredDocument has K1,V1 AND K2,V2 AND K3,V3 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I don't know EF
The challenge is where condition is for single row and the single row does not have multiple values
In TSQL

```
select storedDocumentID 
  from table 
 where (keywork = 'k1'  and value = 'v1') 
    or (keywork = 'k2'  and value = 'v2') 
 group by storedDocumentID 
having count(*) = 2
```

You can also do it with Intersection and Join but I think this is easier

If LINQ won't do it directly you could output the out in hashsets and then take the intersection of the hashsets.

Comment: Your answer is what I was thinking, just didn't think of putting the 'having count...' in sql

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = db.StoredDocumentKeywords;

foreach (var kv in kvlist)
{
    query = query.where (p => p.keyword == kv.Key && p.Value == kv.Value)

}

return query.Select(p => p.StoredDocumentId).Distinct();
```

Comment: I think that would give me a list of StoredDocuments that satisfy ANYTHING in the list.  I need documents that satisfy EVERYTHING in the list.  I'll give it a shot and see though

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that, adjusting my answer